# Can We Make A Tree View For Many2many Generated Table

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have 2 model, `model_1` and `model_2`, 
the `model_1` have `Many2many fields` to `model_2`, Odoo will automatically create a table with name `model_1_model_2` to add relationship between `model_1` and `model_2`.

Is there any way I can create a tree view for `model_1_model_2` table?

***Note**

I want to do that, to import some data to this middle table generated by Odoo from some csv using Odoo import feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately to create a view, You need to have `model` and you need to have the `Id` field.

so if you really need this you can alter the table and add the `Id` column.
create a model with the same name as the relation with `_auto = False`.
and create a the `tree` view to import the data.

```py
   class RelModel(models.Model):
      _name = 'some.name'
      _tabel = 'same_name_in_the_database'
      _auto = False

      mode_1_id = ...Many2one.....
      mode_2_id = ...Many2one.....
```

Hope you find another solution the problem with the tree view it require
the `Id` field and by default `relation table` in Odoo don't have that `field`
otherwise creating the model class for it is enough.